# Case expression inside json_build_object and group by

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to insert a variable_d inside a json object only on the occasions that another variable_c is a specified value. I also need to include variable_d in the GROUP BY statement but again, only when variable_c is the specified value.

Is it possible to do CASE statements inside json_build_object and group by statements? If so I can't get the syntax right.

Ideally I want something like:

```
SELECT json_agg(subquery.*) AS features
FROM
(SELECT json_build_object('variable_a', value_a) 
          AS OBJECT,
        json_build_object('variable_b', value_b, 
          CASE WHEN variable_c = 'yes' THEN 'variable_d', variable_d END) 
          AS properties
 FROM some_table
 GROUP BY variable_a,
          CASE WHEN variable_c = 'yes' THEN variable_d END) subquery
```

Desired output is:

```
[{"object":{"variable_a" : "value"}, "properties":{"variable_b" : "value_b"}}, 
 {"object":{"variable_a" : "value"}, "properties":{"variable_b" : "value_b"}}, 
 {"object":{"variable_a" : "value"}, "properties":{"variable_b" : "value_b"}}, 
 {"object":{"variable_a" : "value"}, "properties":{"variable_b" : "value_b", "variable_d" : "value_d"}}, 
 {"object":{"variable_a" : "value"}, "properties":{"variable_b" : "value_b", "variable_d" : "value_d"}}]
```

Comment: Can you show some example of expected result? The `CASE` is not a problem - the problem is wrongly used aggregation - `json_build_object` is not aggregate function.

Comment: @PavelStehule Updated.

Comment: I can get it to produce the desired output by placing the `CASE WHEN` statement outside of `json_build_object` (not as elegant but it works) and leaving `variable_d` inside `GROUP BY` without the `CASE` statement, but for other reasons I can't have it grouping by `variable_d` when `variable_c` is not `'yes'`

Comment: Grouping means data decomposition to disjunct sets. If you can do it, then you can use GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @PavelStehule I think I understand you, but whenever I try to make `variable_d` in the `GROUP BY` statement dependent on `variable_c = 'yes'` an error returns that `variable_d` must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (presumably since it doesn't when `variable_c` does not equal `'yes'` even though it shouldn't be included in the subquery in that case anyway).

Comment: this is signal, so you are not able to divide data to disjunct sets and operate over these sets

Comment: without sample data, just guessing `SELECT b.value_a, jsonb_agg(dV.value_d),jsonb_agg(bV.value_b)
FROM some_table as b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT value_a,value_d FROM some_table WHERE value_c = 'cond_for_d') as dV ON b.value_a = dV.value_a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT value_a,value_b FROM some_table WHERE value_c = 'cond_for_b') as bV ON b.value_a = bV.value_a
GROUP BY b.value_a` thats collecting by value_a